# Store ROS messages in file?

Tags: ros, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am working on Some project, I have to store ROS messages in some File using C++ API's. I knew ROS BAG files which is excellent for storing ROS messages But i want to knew Is their any other supported files in ROS to store ROS message using C++ API's.
If yes then which one is it ? Can anyone Suggest.

Can I read  ROS .bag file in Reverse order ? If yes then how it can be done. Please can anyone tell me.

image:[image: IMAGE !]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246455/store-ros-messages-in-file-?/) by [Aasiya Shaikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27804/aasiya-shaikh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the rosbag [C++ api](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) to work with data stored in bag files. Including reverse iterating etch. There's API docs [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/rosbag_storage/html/c++/)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aasiya Shaikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27804/aasiya-shaikh/) on 2016-10-27**:
Thanks a lots

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,you can store topic messages in files through ***rostopic echo /topic >>file.txt***

---

Originally posted by [Yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/20790/yang/) with karma: 36 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aasiya Shaikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27804/aasiya-shaikh/) on 2016-10-26**:
Okay Thanks.
Then please can to tell me how I can read these topic messages through API's as I have to reused this messages , in my program .

**Comment by [Yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/20790/yang/) on 2016-10-26**:
1.As ***tfoote*** said,use ***rosbag .***
2.Print the message in file through standard c++.

**Comment by [Aasiya Shaikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27804/aasiya-shaikh/) on 2016-10-27**:
Okay Thank you